# Error starting Turtlebot 2

Tags: turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey,

I am currently using a Turtlebot 2 with ROS groovy.
When I start the script minimal.launch in the package turtlebot_bringup on the robot's laptop, I get the following error :

```
nodelet: /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/DenseStorage.h:69: Eigen::internal::plain_array<T, Size, MatrixOrArrayOptions, 16>::plain_array() [with T = float, int Size = 4, int MatrixOrArrayOptions = 0]: Assertion `(reinterpret_cast<size_t>(array) & 0xf) == 0 && "this assertion is explained here: " "http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/TopicUnalignedArrayAssert.html" " **** READ THIS WEB PAGE !!! ****"' failed.
[FATAL] [1368451090.542690660]: Service call failed!
[FATAL] [1368451090.544932863]: Service call failed!
[FATAL] [1368451090.544932853]: Service call failed!
[mobile_base_nodelet_manager-5] process has died [pid 26924, exit code -6, cmd /opt/ros/groovy/lib/nodelet/nodelet manager __name:=mobile_base_nodelet_manager __log:=/home/turtlebot/.ros/log/687078bc-bbcf-11e2-97f0-446d57c545ae/mobile_base_nodelet_manager-5.log].
log file: /home/turtlebot/.ros/log/687078bc-bbcf-11e2-97f0-446d57c545ae/mobile_base_nodelet_manager-5*.log
[bumper2pointcloud-9] process has died [pid 27236, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/groovy/lib/nodelet/nodelet load kobuki_bumper2pc/Bumper2PcNodelet mobile_base_nodelet_manager bumper2pointcloud/pointcloud:=mobile_base/sensors/bumper_pointcloud bumper2pointcloud/cliff_events:=mobile_base/events/cliff bumper2pointcloud/bumper_events:=mobile_base/events/bumper __name:=bumper2pointcloud __log:=/home/turtlebot/.ros/log/687078bc-bbcf-11e2-97f0-446d57c545ae/bumper2pointcloud-9.log].
```

It seems that the problem come from the bumper2pc node, because if I comment the include tag corresponding to the bumper2pc I don't get the error...

Moreover if I connect the Kobuki base to my desktop computer, I can start the script and everything works perfectly.
All packages are up to date on both computers.

How can I solve this problem ?

Caroline

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/62606/error-starting-turtlebot-2/) by [CarolineQ](https://answers.ros.org/users/4109/carolineq/) on ROS Answers with karma: 395 on 2013-05-13

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Daniel Stonier](https://answers.ros.org/users/51/daniel-stonier/) on 2013-05-13**:
What model/make is your laptop Caroline? Given that your pc is fine with the same software, maybe that can point us toward actually being able to reproduce the problem.

**Comment by [CarolineQ](https://answers.ros.org/users/4109/carolineq/) on 2013-05-13**:
@Daniel : Thanks for your help, the model of my laptop is : Asus Eee PC 1025C.

**Comment by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) on 2013-05-14**:
Another question; do you have 32 or 64 bits OS installed?

**Comment by [CarolineQ](https://answers.ros.org/users/4109/carolineq/) on 2013-05-14**:
@jorge : On the robot's laptop (Asus) I have a 32 bits OS installed, could this be a problem ? Thanks for help.

**Comment by [Daniel Stonier](https://answers.ros.org/users/51/daniel-stonier/) on 2013-05-14**:
Yes, I think we have narrowed down the problem. Eigen will align long, float and double variables differently on 32/64 bit, so what may work on one, might not on the other. We'll try and reproduce here.

**Comment by [Daniel Stonier](https://answers.ros.org/users/51/daniel-stonier/) on 2013-05-14**:
Follow the [bug report](https://github.com/yujinrobot/kobuki/issues/257) on github.

**Comment by [CarolineQ](https://answers.ros.org/users/4109/carolineq/) on 2013-05-14**:
I will follow the bug report. Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We fixed it and released just now. New version should be available soon on shadow-fix repo. Thanks for your inputs!

---

Originally posted by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) with karma: 2284 on 2013-05-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0